# How save property withour rebooting tomacat server?

Tags: java, tomcat, properties, tomcat8

I would like to save "property" not in a separate file, but in the server environment. In order to not reboot the server. "setProperty ()" works in this way in "tomcat" that after reboot, the data is not saved in the configuration, as it is stored in memory. How can I save the values ​​of "property" after a reboot?

```
setProperty("key","value"); //save prop
getProperty("key"); //value - "value"
```

restart server

```
getProperty("key"); //value - null
```

need

```
getProperty("key"); //value - "value"
```

thanks

Comment: which object provides setProperty and getProperty?

Comment: you can set as VCAP variable or Environment variable, or define this as a bean and assign value to it. or you need to read it from a config file.